# How to divide two values from the different row

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have used this formula.

Quote change = (current month data / previous month data) * 100

Then my data stored on SQL SERVER table look like below :

```
id        DATE         DATA

1          2015/01/01   10
2          2015/02/01   20
3          2015/03/01   30
4          2015/04/01   40
5          2015/05/01   50
6          2015/06/01   60
7          2015/07/01   70
8          2015/08/01   80
9          2015/09/01   90
```

How can i implement this formula on SQL Function ?

For Example

```
current month is 2015/02/1
Quote change = (Current Month Data / Previous Month Data ) * 100
Quote change =( 15/10)*100
```

Then if current date is 2015/01/01. Because no data before 2015/01/01, I need to show 0 or #

Comment: Two sub-queries maybe?

Comment: can u explain or give me some example ?

Comment: already edited sql server 2012

Comment: Please avoid using tags in your title.

Comment: Look into the [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql server 2012 have a window function called [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) that is very useful in situations like this.
`Lag` returns the value of a specific column in the previous row (specified by the `order by` part of the `over` clause).

Try this:

```
;With cte as 
(
SELECT Id, Date, Data, LAG(Data) OVER(ORDER BY Date) As LastMonthData
FROM YourTable
)

SELECT Id, 
       Date, 
       Data, 
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(LastMonthData, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (Data/LastMonthData) * 100 END As Quote 
FROM cte
```

I've used a `CTE` just so I wouldn't have to repeat the `LAG` twice.
The `CASE` expression is to prevent an exception in case the LastMonthData is 0 or null.

Comment: @ekremtapan what line?

Comment: CASE WHEN ISNULL(LastMonthData, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (Data/LastMonthData) * 100 END As Quote  CHANGED ---->>>  CASE WHEN ISNULL(LastMonthData, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (LastMonthData/Data)* 100 END As Quote 

working as well ~ 
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join like mentioned below -

```
select a.*,isnull(cast(a.data/b.data as decimal(4,2))*100,0)
from TableA as a
inner join TableA as b
on b.date = dateadd(mm,-1,a.date)
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: This query assumes that the months are consecutive - so there can't be any month missing from the table.